# Scroll to success field in contact form 7 (wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll, contact-form-7

Using Wordpress and the plugin Contact Form 7 I would like to use jQuery to scroll to the sucess message above the contact form.

here is my form

```
<form action="/.../.../#wpcf7-f1581-p853-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
```

I have added the following code to my theme however it is called on reload but doesn't work.

```
var myEl = document.getElementsByClassName('wpcf7-submit');

myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this, chatch the response of contact form and do the magic

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
                  window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
            }, false );
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will scroll (after submit) to the element with result message below the CF7 form, you can adapt it to scroll to your element, just set proper offset and update selector ".wpcf7-response-output" to yours:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
        wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".wpcf7-response-output").offset().top - 100
                }, 500);
            }, 500);
            //console.log("Submited");
        }, false );
    });
});
```